# catch OS X shutting down

Tags: c++, macos, cross-platform, shutdown

Please, help

Cannot find info about how to detect if OS X is now shutting down. In Windows it's simple:

```
if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_SHUTTINGDOWN) != 0) {
    //system is shutting down!
}
```

How to do it on OS X? Or may be cross-platform (Linux too)?

Comment: There's a notification for that. Search for "NSWorkspace" in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can handle SIGTERM signal and it's the same with OS X.

```
void signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
    printf ("Caught signal: %d\n", signum);
}

// Somewhere in the entry point of your application
signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);
```